# Render a component when another component is clicked

Tags: reactjs, state

I want to render `BlackSpark` when `RedSpark` is clicked, but I'm not sure how to change the state of  a component in another component. I know how to set state in the component itself, but how do I affect another component when I click a different component?

```
class BlackSpark extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="black"></div>
        );
    }
}

class RedSpark extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="red"></div>
        );
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
             <BlackSpark />
             <RedSpark />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I know how to set state in the component itself, but how do I affect another component when I click a different component?

The recommended way to do it would be to create a parent component that has the state. You'd then use that state to determine when to render the other child component.

> I want to render BlackSpark when RedSpark is clicked, but I'm not sure how to change the state of a component in another component. Also, what if I want to hide BlackSpark when GreenSpark is clicked and GreenSpark is inside BlackSpark?

In this case, here's how you'd do it.

```
const GreenSpark = ({ onClick }) => (
  <button className="green" onClick={onClick}>X</button>
)

const BlackSpark = ({ onClick }) => (
  <div className="black">
    <GreenSpark onClick={onClick} />
  </div>
)

const RedSpark = ({ onClick }) => (
  <div className="red" onClick={onClick}></div>
)

class Spark extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      showBlack: false
    }

    this.boundShowBlack = this.showBlack.bind(this)
    this.boundHideBlack = this.hideBlack.bind(this)
  }

  showBlack() {
    this.setState({ showBlack: true })
  }

  hideBlack() {
    this.setState({ showBlack: false })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <RedSpark onClick={this.boundShowBlack} />
        {this.state.showBlack && <BlackSpark onClick={this.boundHideBlack} />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI -- I misunderstood the OP's question and thus edited the question wrong. They wanted to show `BlackSpark` only, and show `BlackSpark` AND `RedSpark` when `BlackSpark` is clicked.

Comment: @AndrewLi Thanks! I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Also, `BlackSpark` isn't a component -- it's JSX. You would just do `&& BlackSpark` not `&& <BlackSpark />`.

Comment: Thanks, That was what I needed but what if I will turn off BlackSpark with GreenSpark and GreenSpark is inside BlackSpark?
Like here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgrNNO?editors=0010

Comment: That's a weird request but you'd still put the state in a parent component of BlackSpark so when you click GreenSpark the parent can decided whether or not to show BlackSpark.

Comment: @y'ffre Oh, I now fully understand what you meant. I'd update my answer to show you how to do that as well.

Comment: awww I was so close :D 
Really thanks for Your help, thanks all of you :)

Answer (score 4):

In React, there's a concept of [component composition](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#composing-components) as you've already embraced -- it allows you to accomplish what you want by rendering children based on the parent's state, another key concept known as [lifting state up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html). What this means, is if you have mutually dependent components, create a single parent which composes them, and have state in the parent control the presentation and logic of the children. With the parent `App`, you can keep your state *inside `App`*, and based on `App`'s state, [conditionally render](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html) whatever you want -- either `BlackSpark` or both. For example, using [the logical `&&` operator](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator):

```
{condition && <Component />}
```

This will only render `<Component>` when `condition` is truthy, or else it will not render anything at all (except for when `condition` is 0). Applying it to this situation, try adding state to your `App` component to utilize conditional rendering.

There's another key concept you need to understand: [component props](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html). They are essentially inputs to a component, certain *prop*erties passed to the component to tell how it should behave -- like attributes on regular HTML elements such as input placeholders, URLs, and event handlers. For example:

```
<Component foo="bar" bar={3} />
```

This will pass the props `foo` and `bar` down to `Component` with the values `"bar"` and `3` respectively and are accessible through `this.props`. If you were to access `this.props.foo` inside the `Component` component it would give you `"bar"`. If you pair this up with composition, you can accomplish what you want:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showHello: true
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleChange() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showHello: !prevState.showHello
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.showHello && <Child2 />}
        This is a test.
        <Child1 onClick={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>Click me!</div>
  }
}

class Child2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello!</div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

The above example *lifts state up* by having a parent compose the children and maintain the state. It then uses `props` to pass down an `onClick` handler to `Child1`, so that whenever `Child1` is clicked, *the state of the parent changes*. Once the state of the parent changes, it will use conditional rendering to render `<Child2>` if the condition is truthy. Further reading at [the React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/) and on [the logical `&&` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()).

Comment: Ok, but on website I have component looking like icon and when I click on it I'll show component looking like window and that icon sill have to be there.
Everything what You said happen in one component. My example:
On website you can see only BlackSpark (you can't see RedSpark) when you click on BlackSpark RedSpark will be appear and in effect you can see BlackSpark and RedSpark in the same time.
It's hard do explain, sorry

Comment: @y'ffre Finally, done editing. Should work as you intend.